# How to display my 404 page in Nancy?

Tags: asp.net, .net, nancy

I need to display my 404 error page in Nancy like this

```
if (ErrorCode == 404)
{
  return View["404.html"];
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Be sure to add the Nancy.ErrorHandling namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer from nemesv is correct, but I just wanted to add an example using the ViewRenderer instead of the GenericFileResponse.

```
public class MyStatusHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    private IViewRenderer viewRenderer;

    public MyStatusHandler(IViewRenderer viewRenderer)
    {
        this.viewRenderer = viewRenderer;
    }

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode,
                                  NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        var response = viewRenderer.RenderView(context, "/status/404");
        response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        context.Response = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much better way since it will allow of view engines and layouts. +1

Comment: You could improve this a tiny bit more by using the `WithStatusCode` extension to make `Handle` a one-liner: `context.Response = viewRenderer.RenderView(context, "/status/404").WithStatusCode(statusCode);`

Answer (score 11):

You just need to provide an implementation of the `IStatusCodeHandler` interface (it will be picked up automatically by Nancy).

In the `HandlesStatusCode` method return true for the `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.

And in the `Handle` method you need to set the `Response` property on the `NancyContext` with a response containing your error page content. You can use for example the `GenericFileResponse`:

```cs
public class My404Hander : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, 
                                  NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        var response = new GenericFileResponse("404.html", "text/html");
        response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        context.Response = response;            
    }
}
```